# facebook login using phantom js

Tags: javascript, facebook, phantomjs

i was learning about phantomjs
and i was trying to login into facebook using phantom js

i was successfully able to change the values of the input fields 
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqzBP.jpg)
and i could submit the form

the problem is with multiple redirects that facebook do to reach the home page

here is how my code looks like:

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var page = webpage.create();

page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false;
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;


var loaded = false;
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loaded = false;
  console.log("load started");
};
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loaded = true;
  console.log("load finished");
};


page.open('http://www.facebook.com',function () {
  page.render('1.jpg')


  page.evaluate(function () {
    document.getElementById('m_login_email').value = "me@email.com";
    document.getElementById('m_login_password').value = "*********";
    document.getElementById('login_form').submit();
  });

  page.render('2.jpg');

  setInterval(function () {
    if (loaded) {
      page.render('3.jpg');
      console.log("loaded : "+page.url);
      phantom.exit();
    }
  },1000);


});
```

//EDIT
//the output

```
load started
load finished
load started
load finished
load started
load finished
loaded : https://m.facebook.com/login/async/?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&lwv=100
```

//

that totally work for me but the 3.jpg image it's black image
and the url of this page >>https://m.facebook.com/login/async/?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&lwv=100<<

i was lucky only once, this code worked and i could login .. but it's back to fail again :(

thanks for help BTW

Comment: So... what is your question exactly?

Comment: the page i got is a black screen 8887*2036 why is that happening ? is there anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: Facebooks thinks you're a mobile browser and redirects to the corresponding version of the site. Happens because you didn't set PhantomJS browser viewport which is 400x300 by default.

Comment: Seeing as you aren't heavily invested in PhantomJS yet, may I suggest the switch to [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/)? it is cutting edge whereas PhantomJS is *very* obsolete and well, essentially, dead.

Comment: _“and i was trying to login into facebook using phantom js”_ - don’t. This is explicitly against Facebook’s terms. You should really rather go find another test subject for your “learning” in that regard.

Comment: okay thanks for help :)